# Need help finding a clean expression for exit velocity

Tags: rockets, engines, nozzle, rocket-equation, amateur-rocketry

I'm trying to calculate a engine burning LOX and ethanol (96%) and for that I am using both

- CEAgui, a GUI for NASA's CEA (Chemical Equilibrium with Applications) code
- Sutton's Rocket Propulsion elements 8th edition (2010).

I can find the exit velocity or if I find an equation for it it has something else in it that I don't know the value of. It has become a close circle.

Had anyone else had this problem and been able to overcome the circular referencing I'm seem to be experiencing?

Comment: Depends on the nozzle area ratio mostly. Do you know that?

Comment: @Organic no as I haven't figured out the stagnation temperature and the absolute fluid static temperature. From that, I get the Mach and then I get the ratio. I will have the ratio so the pressure is equal to the outside pressure.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of unknowns. Hopefully one less than the number of equations.

Comment: $v_e = I_{sp} \cdot g_0$, so if you have $I_{sp}$, you can solve for $v_e$. If not, you need to look at other properties. Maybe you can add what you have to the question.

Comment: I've adjusted the wording of your question slightly and made it clearer the sources that you are using, please have a look to make sure it's done accurately, thanks!

Comment: What are your known parameters, besides the fuel composition? In real life it would be done by firing the engine on a test stand, measuring thrust and fuel flow to determine ISp.

Comment: It depends on the aim. Do you need to reach a given velocity V_final and want to determine the rocket's parameters sufficient for this? Or you have a rocket with given masses Mr (empty) and M_fuel and want to find its final velocity?

Comment: In 4th edition of Sutton the equations for velocity as a function of the area ratio are 3-25 and 3-26.  But as other commenters have said, unless you tell us what parameters you know, this is kind of futile.

Comment: I only know what the CEA gave me and the desired thrust. I am trying to build (or at least calculate) a rocket engine first and not the whole rocket. I don't care about how long the engine will burn or the end velocity of the vehicle. If I had that I could calculate the Isp and the other Impulse and then calculate the other stuff. I am trying to make a program similar to the one in this video[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbG2n6ClaCs)  timestamp: 18:00 . Now the L* is the same as theirs but I haven't come far in the book (I jump back en forth for what I believe I need)

Comment: @OrganicMarble  Sorry for the late response. Tagging you just so you see my response if you (probably) haven't. Thank you for the answer(s).

Comment: I'm voting to close this because the OP asked the same question, with more info, elsewhere.